# why this binding not working with class in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
class abc{
 f(){
   console.log("hh")
 }
};

let obj = new abc()
obj.f.bind(this)
```

This function not displaying anything ,If i move function out of class it works .

Comment: `obj.f.bind(this)` returns a new function; your code doesn't do anything with that value.

Comment: please add `this` and the wanted result.

Comment: `obj.f.bind(this)` what do you expect that to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bind()` doesn't change the `this` bindings on the original function. Instead it returns a new function.You need assign that to a variable.

However your code don't have anything related with `this` the code will log `"hh"` whatever `this` is. Log a property of `this` to check what `this` is.

```js
class abc{
 constructor(){
  this.foo = "something"
 }
 f(){
   console.log(this.foo)
 }
};

let obj = new abc()
obj.f() //'something'
let newFunc = obj.f.bind({foo:"changed"});
newFunc() //'changed'
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this works.

```
class abc{
 f(){
   document.write("hh")
 }
};

let obj = new abc()
obj.f()
```